# HTML embedding in c# form application

Tags: c#, html, android-studio, visual-studio-2015, embed

I've recently started to use a e-commerce cart online, and wanted to make a app. But they gave me a HTML code snippet that I can embed in my own website, that I have. But is there a way I can embed this into my c# form application, and a Android Studio application?
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first complete the HTML. The code you've shown is just `div` and `script`. You can't add it to your `webBrowser` because it's not valid HTML.

Complete the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Win Forms App<title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-store-></div>
    <div> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?&data_platform=code&data_date=" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> xProductBrowser("categoriesPerRow=3","views=grid(3,3) list(10) table(20)","categoryView=grid","searchView=list","id=my-store-");
        </script> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Without these `<body> <head> <HTML>` tags you don't have a complete HTML document.

Then you can either do this as a string, or target the ".HTML" source file. Or, or, or. This has quite a bit of flexibility. [See here for the MSDN info on the WebBrowser class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)

As this article describes:

```
// make your string
string myHTML = "<html>...</html>";

WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(); //make you WebBrowser instance

wb.DocumentText = myHTML; //set your HTML
wb.DocmentText = "<html>...</html>";  // you can also do a direct assignment
```

Comment: Hi Kyle. This is exactly what I wanted, so now I entered the code above into a string, and saved the string as "web". So now what. Do I type `webBrowser1.DocumentType = web.Text`, or what ?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see update and use provided link to learn all the ins and outs.

Answer (score 0):

For C# you can embed HTML like this:

Just add a `WebBrowser` control to your form, name it `webBrowser1` (default).
Then in your `Load` or `OnLoad` event add the following line of code:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "your html string";
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code you have is likely JavaScript - not HTML or code that can be used on its own.

I suggest you create a basic html page with a body tag. and surround their code in the `<script>` tag that may be needed. - as above you can use the web browser control to embed... well a web browser in your win forms app.

and set the `DocumentText` property

you may need to pay attention to its properties to allow remote access to resources - that the JavaScript will likely rely on

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Win Forms App<title>
</head>
<body>
<script>There code</script>
</body>
</html>
```